# Phinx migrations - explicit length of integer column

Tags: php, mysql, database-migration, phinx

Can you tell me please if is possible to set explicit length of integer column via Phinx migrations `addColumn()` method?

Documentation uses limit option with `MysqlAdapter::INT_REGULAR` like `['limit' => MysqlAdapter::INT_SMALL, 'signed' => false]` but it automatically sets the length for column e.g. `int(10)`.

But what should I do if I need `int(11)` e.g for foreign key column?

Thx.

Answer (score 4):

As I understood [limit option](http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/migrations.html#limit-option-and-mysql) `MysqlAdapter::INT_REGULAR` is something like predefined types in Phinx. But you can also use your own `limit` variable.

Here is an example:

```
// using Phinx 0.5.4
public function change() {
  $table = $this->table('papers');
  $table->addColumn('user_id', 'integer', ['limit' => 2])
        ->addColumn('book_id', 'integer') // by default will be int(11)
        ->addColumn('bank_id', 'integer', ['limit' => 32])
        ->create();
```

}

MySQL describe results:

```
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id | int(2)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| book_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| bank_id | int(32) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

To get more information please check the [source code](https://github.com/robmorgan/phinx/blob/0.6.x-dev/src/Phinx/Db/Adapter/MysqlAdapter.php#L735) of `getSqlType()` and [source code](https://github.com/robmorgan/phinx/blob/0.6.x-dev/src/Phinx/Db/Adapter/MysqlAdapter.php#L871) of `getPhinxType()` functions.